# Accessing virtual serial port with node.js gives either error or no open event

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I'm trying to access a virtual serial port created with http://www.hhdsoftware.com/virtual-serial-ports on Windows 8.

When I use a terminal emulator (Realterm) to access the port, it seems to work; well, I see characters I type in the output file, I do not see anything from the input file in the emulator window, but to be honest the UI of the emulator is overwhelming and I don't fully understand what I'm doing.

But I actually want to access the port using the [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) module for node.js. This is my JS code:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;


var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", {
    // these are the default values in Realterm that seem to work there
    baudRate: 57600,
    dataBits: 8,
    stopBits: 1,
    parity: 'none',
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
}, true, function(error){
  if ( error ) {
    console.log('failed to open: '+error);
  } else {
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('data received: ' + data);
    });
    serialPort.write("ls\r\n", function(err, results) {
      console.log('err ' + err);
      console.log('results ' + results);
    });
  } 
});
```

My problem is that when I run the above code, I only get an error:

> failed to open: Error: SetCommState: Unknown error code 87

What's really strange is that I only get this error when I run the code *before* accessing the port with Realterm. After closing Realterm, I do not get this error, but instead there is simply no output, i.e. the code doesn't receive the "open" event.

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try using `0` instead of `1` for `stopBits`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4189646/2646526

Comment: Possibly 2 issues. The error could be that the port is already open in RealTerm. It can't be opened by two things at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) you're using is calling [SetCommState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363436(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
if (!SetCommState(file, &dcb)) {
    ErrorCodeToString("SetCommState", GetLastError(), data->errorString);
    return;
}
```

To configure the communication of your virtual serial port. Then it checks the errors the function [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) returns:

```
void ErrorCodeToString(const char* prefix, int errorCode, char *errorStr) {
  switch(errorCode) {

case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
    _snprintf(errorStr, ERROR_STRING_SIZE, "%s: File not found", prefix);
    break;
  case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
    _snprintf(errorStr, ERROR_STRING_SIZE, "%s: Invalid handle", prefix);
    break;
  case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
    _snprintf(errorStr, ERROR_STRING_SIZE, "%s: Access denied", prefix);
    break;
  case ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED:
    _snprintf(errorStr, ERROR_STRING_SIZE, "%s: operation aborted", prefix);
    break;
  default:
    _snprintf(errorStr, ERROR_STRING_SIZE, "%s: Unknown error code %d", prefix, errorCode);
    break;
  }
}
```

The *unknown error* 87 is not checked but it means that an [INVALID PARAMETER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) has been passed when opening the port. The problem is that *GetLastError* function is not going to give more information to clarify which param is causing the error.

Since you can't do anything on Realterm, I think it doesn't work either on it.

After reading the home page of [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport), I noticed it provides two tools for playing with serial ports: serialportlist & serialportterm, try with the last one and see if you can open the port from there.

The most usual error with serial ports is setting wrong the baud speed rate. I suppose you've already tried several speeds, but in case you don't, try with the valid ones:

115200, 57600, 38400, 19200, 9600, 4800, 2400, 1800, 1200, 600, 300, 200, 150, 134, 110, 75, or 50